# wipe div data and hide slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have been working on a jquery slider which slides out once a record is clicked and then when u click close it slides back off the screen.. the issue i orginally had was if i clicked on the record twice it would try load the same infomation on top of it self and created heaps of errors.. so i found some code which i could use to deelte all the data and then move the slider pane back accross the screen the issue im having is it wipes all the details like i wont but the slider pane doesnt move at all i have only put the javascript code here to see if anyone can tell me what im doing wrong with the code and how to fix it if possible...

```
    function deleteParentElement(){
         $(this).parent().animate({right:-1000});    // on its own as an onlcick event 
attached to the button it works on its own the pane its moving class is called "details"
         $('.student').remove()   //the class defined in here is only the div containing the data
         e.stopPropagation()
    }
```

this is the button used to trigger the function

```
<button style="position: absolute; top:40px; right:25px;" href="#" id="bt-close" class="<? echo $Stu_id;?>" onClick="deleteParentElement()">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two semicolons and a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//the rest of the code
});
```

... That's probably your problem

Comment: after $('.student').remove(); and e.stopPropagation();... every time in jquery you have a command like remove(), you need a semicolon after it (unless it's not the end of the command, like parent().hide();)... this also goes for event hadlers like $(document).ready(function(){
//the rest of the code
});